# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' in Laravel/Vue Application

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I am working on a Laravel/Vue Single Page Application but in the very beginning I got an error saying:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Here is my `app.blade.php` which is a layout file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<!-- CSRF Token -->
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

<title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>

<!-- Fonts -->
<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Styles -->
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-white shadow-sm">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}">
            {{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data- target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="{{ __('Toggle navigation') }}">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

            </ul>

            <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <!-- Authentication Links -->
                @guest
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('login') }}">{{ __('Login') }}</a>
                    </li>
                    @if (Route::has('register'))
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('register') }}">{{ __('Register') }}</a>
                        </li>
                    @endif
                @else
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre>
                            {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
                        </a>

                        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                               onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                             document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                {{ __('Logout') }}
                            </a>

                            <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                @csrf
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                @endguest
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<main class="py-4">
    @yield('content')
</main>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the `home.blade.php`:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

   <App></App>

@endsection
```

Here is `web.php`:

```
<?php

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/{any}', 'AppController@index')->where('any', '.*');
```

Below is the `app.js` file:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import router from './router';
import App from './components/App';

require('./bootstrap');

const app = new Vue({
el: '#app',

components: {
    App
},
 router
});
```

Below is the `router.js` file that includes `routes`:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import ExampleComponent from './components/ExampleComponent';

Vue.use(VueRouter);

export default new VueRouter({
routes: [
    { path: '/', component: ExampleComponent },
],

mode: 'history'
});
```

I have placed all the `code` here in this question and there is nothing extra that causes the error.

Here is a screenshot of the `Network` tab which does not show any `404`:

[image: Network tab]

Comment: What response do you get which causes the error?

Comment: @VLAZ Response is only the the `Login` and `Registration` buttons, the `App` component is not displayed.

Comment: What is the *network response* you get which causes the error? You are calling something and expect JSON back, however, the response is most likely HTML. Find that content and see what it says. It's very likely an error that will at least give you a hint of what to look at.

Comment: @VLAZ : I have not yet called anything yet, the app is in the very initial stage, I have added all the files and the code in the post. I do not have anything else.

Comment: @GregSchmidt this is an error coming from JavaScript when parsing a string as JSON yet it "<". Usually, that's because it's trying to parse something like "<html>some error</html>". It's not a syntax error in PHP but one of the routes produces invalid JSON. And most likely an error page. It might be a missing route (so you get a page describing a 404) or some server error (resulting in 500) or something along those lines.

Comment: This is a javascript error, not a PHP error. Open up your browser's developer tools to inspect the network request that failed and go from there. You may not have made any calls yet, but Vue certainly has. One of them is probably returning HTML instead of the expected JSON.

Comment: If you go to the Network tab in developer console in Chrome it's highly probable you will find at least one network request colored red. Most likely, one of them is a 404 error returned by your server from an endpoint from which your app is expecting JSON. The error is caused by the app's inability to parse an HTML response (containing tags, starting with `<`) as JSON. We can't find the faulty request for you, nor can we advise on how to change either the request or the server so it doesn't happen. Not from what you have provided so far.

Comment: Click on that network request for “app.js” and see what its actual contents are. Probably some HTML page, not JS code.

Comment: @deceze : I clicked it, it shows the same homepage.

Comment: So that means your server is serving the same HTML page for whatever URL you request. There’s your problem.

Comment: @deceze @tao @Greg : The issue is found, it was due to the `asset()` function not properly picking the `app.js` file from the `public` directory. Now I changed it to `asset('public/js/apps.js')` and it worked fine. If the question is reopened, I can post my asnwer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is found and it was coming from the `asset()` function of laravel as it could not pick up the `app.js` from the `public` directory for some reasons which caused the application to return the `html` page because in the `web.php`, I have told it to hit the same controller action for anything that comes after the `/` in the url. Now I edited the line `<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>` and changed it to `<script src="{{ asset('public/js/app.js') }}" defer></script>` which picks the `js` file properly and returns the `js code` that handles the `Single Page Application routes` and I do not see the issue anymore.

Thank you all for participating and helping me find out the issue.